# what is wrong with my shell script for word guessing game?

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a script for word guessing in bash.
But is not working properly.

```
w = "@@@"
read -p "input word: " var

while [ "$w" != "$var" ]
do
echo "Wrong."
read -p "input word: " var
done
echo "Right answer"
```

Comment: Always try https://www.shellcheck.net/ first.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\c` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have spaces when declaring varaible:

```sh
code="banana"
```